# Метка "плохой код"

Tags: обсуждение, метки, модерация

В своё время предложил метку "говнокод", но при последующем использовании - правку отклонили с формулировкой "мы меняем представление людей о способе общения в Рунете - оно должно быть доброжелательным, без унижения, ругани..". Я полностью согласен с такой постановкой вопроса, однако нам нужна похожая метка для "плохого кода". Код который работает но "лучше так не делать". Чтобы новички в программировании которые найдут вопрос в гугле могли сразу понять - что-то с этим кодом не так.

Comment: @igumnov http://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/

Comment: @Athari Да, да суровые реалии, с 20 ого ответа сработала сортировочка. Но идея хорошая, очень сильно доставило, раньше не видел, спасибо.

Comment: Вряд ли пользователь будет создавать вопрос сразу с меткой "плохой код" (а к ответу метку вообще не применить), действительно, лучшее место для сообщения об этом - комментарий.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Вот как раз в комментариях можно обидеть человека, а какая-то нейтральная метка (более нейтральная чем "твой-код-херня" или "говнокод") могут натолкнуть на мысль что надо что-то менять ...

Comment: @Caravus, согласитесь, что комментарий можно написать так, чтобы не обидеть человека. И появление метки не решает проблему плохого кода в ответах к вопросу. И, как заметил Athari, это [мета-метка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev ой да ладно, набросились тут на меня все. Вместо того чтобы решать проблему вы предлагаете её игнорировать, перекладывать на плечи отвечающих. Как думаете кто-то будет объяснять в комментариях почему код плохой, если этого не в вопросе? Если да - почему этого не происходит сейчас?

Comment: @Caravus, вроде никто не набросился. Смотрите: если пользователь сам знает, что код плохой, то он может попросить в вопросе о предложениях по улучшению (кроме основной проблемы), а если он не знает об этом, то это можно указать в ответе на вопрос, навешивание метки, боюсь, не решит эту проблему. Тема важная, не спорю, но над решением стоит поразмыслить. Введение мета-метки не похоже на выход.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Для "подумать" этот вопрос и был создан, но я почему-то вижу тут только отрицательные ответы. Вопрос "чего хочет" или "не хочет" пользователь - это другая проблема, я её не поднимал. Я же говорю о том что люди приходят с поиска, видят код и копируют его себе, а потом люди которые мне тут пишут "не надо" жалуются что им в очередной раз достался в наследство проект который видимо писали какие-то индусы. На самом деле нет, на самом деле просто тот кто писал код не знал что этот код - плохой.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если метка и не нужна, то такие вопросы надо выпиливать, как портящие карму сети знаний. Костыли - это анти-знания. Если что-то "работает", это не значит, что другие должны пользоваться этими костылями. "Смотрите, на [ru].SO написано, что надо делать так, вот и я буду запросы в цикле делать!" ЗЫ Аналогичная дискуссия была сегодня в чате, решили немного по-другому, но по каждому топику так не будешь доводы приводить...

Comment: между прочим `плохой код` - это весьма объективная характеристика, т.о, __мета-меткой не является__. По существу,  большая часть вопросов возникает, по причине того, что люди пишут плохой код, в котором там и тут грабли.  Такая метка как-раз смотрит в корень проблемы, вместо того, чтобы формировать листики, чем тут любят заниматься. Это ведь чистый формализм, с определённой точки зрения.

Answer (score 12):

Метка *не нужна*.

---

Это мета-метка, такие метки запрещены.

Если вы видите плохой код в ответе, это плохо, поставьте минус и откомментируйте. Также можете исправить код, если это не изменит смысла ответа (например, если в коде опечатка или недочёт, не связанные напрямую с обсуждаемой в вопросе проблемой).

Если вы видите плохой код в вопросе, это нормально, поставьте минус и откомментируйте. Если кто-то копирует код из вопроса, то ССЗБ.

Comment: А что там с плагином для VS, который должен предлагать код со SO?

Comment: в английской версии есть метка *anti-pattern*, и тут __нужен__ аналог.

Comment: @11111000000 Полагаю, анти-паттерн для обсуждения анти-паттернов: определение, нахождение, уничтожение. То есть предметом обсуждения является анти-паттерн. Если в вопросе просто плохой код, то вопрос неверно помечать этой меткой, потому что предметом обсуждения являются иные вещи.

Comment: так в том то и дело - это же повод указать, почему код - плохой, это обучает, по-моему - то, что нужно

Comment: `плохой код` - __не мета-метка__, а объективная характеристика и корень большей части левых вопросов

Comment: @11111000000 Ознакомьтесь с критериями мета-метки.

Comment: именно ознакомившись, я это и написал. Читайте выше подробней. Можно метить `анти-паттерн`, хотя это не по-русски и генерирует флейм.

Answer (score 9):

Согласен с ответом @Athari, метка не нужна.

---

Не уверен, стоит ли голосовать против вопроса, в котором есть плохой код. Все таки автор задает вопрос именно потому что он не знает чего-то. Скорее всего, лучшим способом будет ответ, в котором вы можете указать автору на проблемы, которые вы видите.

Если возвращаться к теме вашего вопроса, то скорее всего, автор вопроса может не догадываться, что его код низкого качества. Как результат, добавив подобную метку, вы можете не просто обидеть человека, но и более того, отбить все желание общаться в сообществе в будущем.

Comment: Таким образом, давайте у нас будет много-много пользователей, которые будут выкладывать плохой код, зато они будут довольны? Или у нас тут всё-таки сообщество "чтоб сделать мир немного лучше"?

Comment: @Caravus: люди не рождаются с правильной культурой программирования, но этому навыку можно научиться. Можно оставить комментарий, который указывает на проблемы в коде (не относящиеся к сути вопроса)—можно не оставлять, так это не очень эффективный метод. Проблема, когда плохой код копируется в *ответ* — вот здесь обязательно надо голосовать "против", если автор ответа отказывается исправить код.

Comment: ничего страшного, если такой "обиженный" больше не станет генерировать пустые, мусорные вопросы. С другой стороны, минусы мотивируют особенно упорных продолжать биться головой об стену, вместо того, чтобы использовать и то и другое по назначению.

Comment: @11111000000 Главная цель сообщества, в контексте обсуждаемого вопроса, - помощь знаниями, а не ругань. Обидев человека, мы лишь породим злость и обиду, а хотелось бы тягу к знаниям. Представьте, что бы было, если бы вместо терпеливых подсказок наши преподаватели использовали бы обидные слова. Скорее всего, подобное поведение просто отпугнет людей от глубокого изучения профессии.

Comment: перечитал топик, - никто не предложил более лучше ругаться, я так вообще считаю, как и написал выше, что минусы - обиднее метки и в то же время не направляют автора вопроса в нужном русле. Заметил, что такие часто пишут новый вопрос, практически идентичный заминусованному, т.к. причину часто не трудятся раскрыть. Побуду КО - наша цель тут не количество, а качество. Обсуждаемая метка предполагает  улучшение качества, через соответствующий комментарий с пояснением, поэтому я - за неё.

Comment: @11111000000 Вы совершенно правильно подчеркнули, наша цель - именно качество знаний в сообществе. Для этого мы вместе [создаем комментарии](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/) и [улучшаем причины закрытия вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/). С помощью ясных комментариев и понятных причин закрытия вопросов мы пытаемся обучать новых участников сообщества качественно новому формату общения, тому, который хотим видеть на Stack Overflow на русском.

Comment: @11111000000 Замечу, что на мой взгляд, голос против, голос за закрытие и комментарий - это проявление свободы слова и мнения, но метка - это уже ярлык.

Comment: в чём то вы правы, но семантика построена именно на метках, я вот люблю пользоваться https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi для емакса и  фильтровал бы код с такой меткой, это лишь одно из применений, но да, позиция понятна

Answer (score -2):

А я считаю, метка - **нужна**. В английской версии есть метка `anti-pattern`

---

Многие вопросы с *плохокодом* минусовать не станут, будь они того и достойны, т.к:

1. сам вопрос может быть неплохо сформулирован, не хочется пугать вопрошатора
2. отвечающему этот вопрос - лишний рейтинг
3. вопрос всё-равно не удалят, ввиду наличия хороших ответов

Комментировать такие вопросы, для специалиста - боль и унижение, метку поставить проще.

А вот для парсеров SO, поиска и новичков, изучающих хорошие практики, такая метка действительно была бы сигналом **включить критическое мышление**

Нам нужны **качественные** вопросы, с релевантными ответами.

К тому-же, получив такую метку, автор не испугается, но будет думать два раза перед отправкой следующей порции своего *творчества*, что ресурсу на пользу.

Comment: Лично для меня - примерно 80-90% вопросов вызываны "плохим кодом". по некоторым меткам - так все 100%. Не нравится вопрос - проходите мимо.

Comment: Метка нужна, но развешивать такие ярлыки на чужие вопросы некорректно. Другое дело, если вопрошающий **сам** помечает так свой вопрос (тем самым просит совета об улучшении кода).

Comment: Полностью согласен с @avp - на мой взгляд, оценка людей, как и их способностей выходит за пределы нашей компетенции.  Если вы видите вопрос, которому по вашему мнению не место на сайте, пожалуйста, используйте сигнал тревоги. На случай, если вопрос не удовлетворяет «взглядам на жизнь«, [сообщество создало](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928/) [рекомендаций](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly).

Comment: Согласен и полагаю, что автор топика тоже разделяет гуманистические идеалы нашего сообщества. Дело в том, что метка "плохой код"  оценкой касаемой личности, либо же агрессией, по отношению к задающему вопрос, не является. Согласен, что по русски это словосочетание может нести негативную эмоциональную окраску, однако аналогичная по смыслу метка нужна.